# Best way to run a search from two tables that are linked to each other (with a FK)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table that contains all the data about `users`. `Users` can however have multiple `email` adresses so i need to store them in a seperate table.

I want to run searches based on an `email` adresses that return all the information about the `user`. (i also want to be able to search the user table by username which is stored in the user table) 
What is the best way to store the email adresses in my database??
I dont think introducing a redundant email adress field in the user table is a good idea, but possibly it is??

for now i have a user table linked to the email table with 1:M relationship.
(so email adress contains user_id as part of its primary key)

after i store the email adresses what is the best way to get all the information with mySql query (so please include mySQL in your answer)

I know about `JOIN` opperation but i dont know how to use it with this search.

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html What have you tried and what have you read? This looks like a simple JOIN oepration to me.

Comment: if the question is simple just answer it. I tried looking for an answer like this but i was having hart time finding it in exact format. I know about about join opperation but i ussually just design the database and dont write the sql code for it. Its just difficult for me to understand the syntax so i came here for help. I will try the answer that is allready there but it doesnt look so simple for me because im new to sql and for example things like "users.id = emails.user_id" are still confusing for me. I will try to figure it out soon and will accept the best answer.

Comment: There already was an answer so I didn't need to provide one, but even if I did answer I would downvote your question as well. The downvote is because you haven't included what you have tried and you haven't shown us that you did any research on the subject. If you do know about JOIN then please say so in your question and include some of the JOIN queries you tried. A good question should include such things, that's why I've taken the time to write a page describing my downvote in detail.

Comment: I didnt know if join operation was the best way to preform such task. I am not upset at the downvote, I just dont want you to think im spamming the site. I am just very ignorant about the topic despite trying to research it further. In a couple of days i will no longer be asking questions like this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your data like that, assuming all emails are unique (I added `UNIQUE KEY` there)

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You can retrieve data for specific email like that:

```
SELECT users.*, emails.email
FROM users
JOIN emails ON users.id = emails.user_id
WHERE emails.email = 'some_mail@example.com'
```

You can also select all emails user have like so:

```
SELECT users.*, GROUP_CONCAT(emails.email) 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN emails ON users.id = emails.user_id
WHERE users.id = 1234
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE emails DROP KEY email, ADD PRIMARY KEY email_pk (email);` (ok, just splitting hairs ;)

Comment: And while we are at it, let's also `ALTER TABLE emails ADD CONSTRAINT user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id);` (assuming you use InnoDB engine). I'm out ;)

Answer (score -1):

`table user_email with (id_user,email)`

after that you can do search by email or user id